# Web-scraping: how to choose proxy

Tags: java, heroku, proxy, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to write as reusable as possible web scraper. I gonna write it on Selenium + PhantomJS. PhantomJS will use a pool of IPs (proxies). There is a huge list of free proxies, [for example](https://free-proxy-list.net/).

*How could I choose at runtime the best proxy for specific URL?* By the best I mean the fastest an one which won't be blocked with target resource.

### Workarround

I deployed my simplest app on Heroku. The app serves some html content. I used different proxies (with response time < 300ms) instead of `151.252.120.177:8080` (see code below), and noticed that most of them aren't able to parse simplest html in 15 seconds timeout. And some of them (that are even slower) retrieved content in a second. *Why some proxies are unable to reach my content? Are they blacklisted with Heroku?*

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);        
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "drivers/phantomjs");

    ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
    cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=151.252.120.177:8080");
    cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=socks");
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);

    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.get(REMOTE_URL);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("btn-success")));
    element.click();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: yes, there is a big chance they could be blacklisted. About choosing the best one, I would say you could store wait time per proxy/domain yourself and then choose which could be most beneficial according to your own data. I don't see other way really.

Comment: maybe choosing the one that is closer in geographic terms? but of course if that proxy is banned, that won't be beneficial at all. Another alternative would be to use some paid systems that do this, like `crawlera` or `proxymesh`

Answer (score -2):

If you need just a scraper result you can use free scrapers with proxy support. Try this one http://datathief.verych.ru/

Comment: they look pretty suspicious, just exe file from empty web site. Thanks, but I will write my own

Comment: don't worry, I wrote it for my goals, but it became a very generic. I don't have a time to create a website :(
There is a video, but I'm afraid a very poor quality https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz1xzyHdtQg